# MKS how to display all Revisions of a member

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

I want to have a list of all revisions of a member.

Also for branches.

I know how to do for subprojects, but didn't find a solution for Members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the **si rlog** command, as you can change the layout quite easy.

The following example shows just the revision numbers

```bash
si rlog --format="{revision}\n" --noHeaderFormat --noTrailerFormat member
```

The same result gives

```bash
si viewhistory --fields=revision member
```

Review also the usage page for both commands.

And of course the above commands imply that you are working in the correct sandbox. Otherwise you'd need to specify the project.

Comment: The first instruction with rlog doesn't display anything but the secondone with viewHistory does. But I have no clue why.

Answer (score 0):

```
si rlog --format="{revision}\n" --project=%Path% --noHeaderFormat --noTrailerFormat member
```

- this way should work